# Accordion with buttons on its right side

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I am trying to implement an  [accordion from w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) with buttons on its right. this guide has a button with class='accordion', and when pressed it shows the . 
What im trying to do is, have the accordion button have a "Object AAA" from my database, when the accordion button is clicked, the panel comes down with some info on that object. The buttons, and 'Edit' and a 'Delete' button, will be for the "Object AAA" . Because there will be a couple of Objects in the database (Object AAA, Object BBB, etc) I cannot have the buttons be placed anywhere else other than next to the accordion button. I tried placing them, and did it but then the panel doesn't open like you can see in the fiddle. if i place them above the accordion(even if there is another accordion above) then the panel drops fine(this way i can place the buttons on the left side of the accordion) but i want them  to align right, on the same vertical level with the button with the class .accordion

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnwLqgbo/)

```
<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<button class="dlt">Delete</button>
<button class="edit">Edit</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
```

Any idea on how its possible to put them on the right side? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking - you want the buttons to align right, vertically level with the button with the class `.accordion`?

Comment: the headers are themselves implemented as buttons currently, which is hindering you. You'd need to re-implement those as something else (e.g. divs if you want to place more buttons within them)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want, sorry didnt have the words to express it correctly

Comment: once you do that you can put the buttons within the divs and float the buttons to the right hand side using CSS